# Laravel Dusk - test says it cannot see content for specified URL

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-dusk

I am writing an automated test for my laravel application using laravel dusk, and I am using the assetSee method to test that the program can see some of the text that's on the resulting page.

The text is definitely on the page, but laravel dusk cannot see it.

// routes

```
    Route::get('/clients/create', ['as' => 'clients.create', 'uses' => 'clients_controller@create']);
```

// clients_controller

```
     public function create()
        {
            return view('clients.create');
        }
```

// view (clients.create)

```
    <div class="table-container">
    
            <a class="back-link" href="{{ route('clients.index') }}">< Back</a>
    
            <h2 style="clear: left">Add a Client</h2>
    
            <form method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('clients.store') }}">
            @csrf
    
                <div class="form-input">
                    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                    <input id="first_name" name="first_name" class="first_name" value="">
    
                </div>
                <div class="form-input">
                    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                    <input id="last_name" name="last_name" class="last_name" value="">
    
                </div>
                <div class="form-input">
                    <label for="avatar">Avatar</label>
                    <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" class="avatar" value="">
    
                </div>
                <div class="form-input">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input id="email" name="email" class="email" value="">
                </div>
    
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit" value="Add">
    
            </form>
                
        </div>
```

// Dusk test

```
    namespace Tests\Browser;
    
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
    use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
    use Tests\DuskTestCase;
    
    class CreateClientTest extends DuskTestCase
    {
        /**
         * A Dusk test example.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function testExample()
        {
            $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
                $browser->visit('/clients/create')
                        ->assertSee('Add a Client');
            });
        }
    }
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what the issue might be?

Thanks,

Robert

London, UK

Comment: If you dump the html with `$browser->visit('/clients/create')->dump();` can you see the _Add a Client_ text?

Comment: Hmm, no. I think it might be something to do with the authentication though, as when I visit that page straight from Google, I don't see the text either. I think I need to log the user out, then login again with a username and password, then go to that URL, and place that all in dusk. But thanks for that dump method anyway, very useful! :)

Comment: This was the issue. I have actually added a separate function, setup(), in a helpers.php file, that logs the user out and into the app again. I am then calling this function from each of my test files.